# Is this a clearfix issue involving cards?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am currently working on a project that involves displaying items and I am using bootstrap v4 to build a responsive front end.

Problem:
I ran into this problem that involves the usage of the card class, the first card of every row has a height that takes up the entirety of the row height (if that makes any sense). I have tried to look up fixes to this problem and have tried adding divs with class clear fix before every row but I still think it is a clearfix issue, although not clear on how to fix it. I would like to have the first card in each row to be uniform with every other card on the row; sort of like the second and third column cards.

thanks in advance!

solution:

```
display: flex;
```

[image: results]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" id="item_card">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./itemimgs/creamy-no-stir.png" id="itemImg">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <p class="card-text">trader joe's peanut butter</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="item_card">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./itemimgs/greatvaluepb.jpeg" id="itemImg">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">kirkland peanut butter</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="item_card">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./itemimgs/smuckers.jpeg" id="itemImg">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">schmuckers peanut butter</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" id="item_card">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./itemimgs/skippy_pb.jpg" id="itemImg">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">schmuckers peanut butter</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="item_card">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./itemimgs/justins.jpeg" id="itemImg">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">schmuckers peanut butter</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>...
```

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten to apply the flexbox classes. BS4 doesn't use floats AFAIK...so no clearfix.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/utilities-for-layout/

Comment: thanks for answering my newbie question!